# PFQueryTableViewController - Getting different objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I've two *Parse* tables, **Users** and **Evaluations** that are connected by a pointer reference to **User.ref (a pointer to itself)** -> **Evaluations.evaluatedId (a user pointer)**

In my *PFQueryTableViewController* I need to get all users list with their last evaluation. I'm trying with:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery
{
    let userQuery = PFUser.query()!

    let evaluationQuery = PFQuery(className: "Evaluations")
    evaluationQuery.whereKey("evaluatorId", matchesKey: "ref", inQuery: userQuery)

    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userQuery, evaluationQuery])
    query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    return query
}
```

But I'm getting this **error**:

*'All sub queries of an `or` query should be on the same class.'*

**I've searched for a while and I found this:**

*When using orQueryWithSubqueries, each subquery should be for the same class. If you need to query different classes, you will need either a separate query for each, or use whereKey:matchesQuery: if the other class is pointed to by the parent class.*

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use .includeKey()? It will include the objects being pointed to in the column you specify.

Comment: @Acoop I think .includeKey won't work in that case because I need to get all the user lists and the last evaluation for every one. It's a 1:N relation then I need to query Users as main but the reference is in Evaluation table :(

Comment: Why not maintain a pointer to the last evaluation for every user? Make an `afterSave` Cloud Code hook which updates the pointer for the calling user. Then you could use `includeKey` when querying User

Comment: @Russell it's a good idea but in some cases I will need to know the last Evaluation for a concrete Evaluator...

Comment: What do you mean by "concrete Evaluator"?

Comment: @Russell an evaluator is an user that can evaluate other users. When the evaluator log in in the app I need to show him the list of his users. For every row in this list I need to show the last evaluation created by him. Thanks!

Comment: Since every row is a user, wouldn't the pointer to the last evaluation work?